# What does it mean to define $f^{-1}(a)$ in the context of level sets, tangent planes and normals?

Tags: vector-analysis

What does it mean to define $f^{-1}(a)$ in the context of level sets, tangent planes and normals?

E.g. I have an exercise that starts like:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x,y,z)=e^{x+2y}\cos(z)-xz+y$
and $S=f^{-1}(2)$, where $S$ is the level set.

So what does the $f^{-1}(2)$ actually define and how is it used in the context of level sets, tangent planes and normals, e.g. in the above exercise?

Comment: It's the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that $f$ maps to $2$. So for any $(x,y,z) \in S$, we have $f(x,y,z) = 2$. It's a level surface.

Comment: Why does it use the notation of inverse function?

Comment: It's a slight abuse of notation but think of what $f$ maps the set $f^{-1}(a)$ to - this is just the set $\{a\}$. And in the case that $f$ has an inverse, the set $f^{-1}(a)$ has only one element, and this is the value of the inverse function at $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S=f^{-1}(2)$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$
e^{x+2y}\cos(z)-xz+y=2 \quad \mbox{for} \quad (x,y,z)\in S
$$
so it is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ analougous to a level curve for a function  of two variables.